# How to run a while loop as long as there is no error

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I am running a code that might get an error, but I want to run it as long as
there is no error.

I thought about something like that:

```
while ValueError:
    try:
        x = int(input("Write a number: "))
    except ValueError:
        x = int(input("You must write a number: "))`
```

Comment: @jonrsharpe What happened to your shiny gold hammer?

Comment: @BhargavRao no [tag:python] in the initial revision (or no gold badge in [tag:python-3.x], depending on how you look at it!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were quite near

```
while True:
    try:
        x = int(input("Write a number: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("You must write a number: ")
```

To know more about exception handling, refer the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#tut-handling)

Comment: Thanks for that @Padraic ... Used to not using brains!

Comment: What about an `else` block?

Comment: @Zizouz212 That's more *Pythonic*, this is more *intuitive*. You can choose whatever you like! :)

Comment: I'll post an answer mentioning it. :)

Comment: @Zizouz212 Cool! Nice answer also

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to Bhargav's answer, I figured I would mention one other option:

```
while True:
    try:
        x = int(input("Write a number: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("You must write a number: ")
    else:
        break
```

The `try` statement executes. If an exception is thrown, the `except` block takes over, and it's run. The `else` block is executed if no exception is thrown. And don't worry, if the `except` block ever executes, the `else` block won't be called. :)

Also, you should note that this answer is considered to be more Pythonic, while Bhargav's answer is arguably easier to read and more intuitive.