# How to do exception handling in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception

```
elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//label[@class = 'checkbox' and contains(.,'Últimos 15 días')]/input")
if ( elem.is_selected() ):
    print "already selected"
else:
    elem.click()
```

In my code `elem.click()` gets gives an error sometimes. If it does, I need to call `elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath` again i.e. the first line of the code.

Is there a way to achieve this using exception handling in python.
Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: See this answer for exception handling syntax: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730764/try-except-in-python-how-do-you-properly-ignore-exceptions/2390566#2390566

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Python try until no error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606919/in-python-try-until-no-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can understand this can be done with exception handling.
you could try the following:

```
elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//label[@class = 'checkbox' and contains(.,'Últimos 15 días')]/input")
if ( elem.is_selected() ):
    print "already selected"
else:
    while True:
        try:
            #code to try to run that might cause an error
            elem.click() 
        except Exception:
            #code to run if it fails
            browser.find_element_by_xpath
        else:
            #code to run if it is the try is successful
            break
        finally: 
            #code to run regardless
```

Comment: elem.click() needs to run several time before it stops throwing an exception. How can I handle this situation?

Comment: Add the whole try block into a while loop and break it only when it is successful eg. 
`while True:`
    `try:`
       ` #command`
    `except Exception:`
        `#error code`
    `break`
- sorry still getting use to formatting comments

Comment: I will add it to my answer

Answer (score 0):

You need try/except statement there.

```
try:
  elem.click()
except Exception: # you need to find out which exception type is raised
  pass
  # do somthing else ...
```

Comment: But wouldn't that try block execute just once? I need to call elem.click() until it executes and does not gives an error.

Comment: You can use this code in a loop. You only need to find good control flow for it. Maybe retry until reaches max retry.

Answer (score 0):

generic way to handle exception in python is

```
try:
    1/0
except Exception, e:
    print e
```

So in your case it would give

```
try:
    elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//label[@class =     'checkbox' and contains(.,'Últimos 15 días')]/input")

except Exception, e:
    elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath

if ( elem.is_selected() ):
    print "already selected"
else:
    elem.click()
```

It is better to use the more specific exception type. If you use the generic Exception class, you might catch other exception where you want a different handling

Answer (score 0):

Look at `try` and `except`

```
while elem == None:
    try:
        elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//label[@class = 'checkbox' and contains(.,'Últimos 15 días')]/input")
        if ( elem.is_selected() ):
            print "already selected"
        else:
            elem.click()
    except Exception, e:
        elem = None
```

Obviously using the specific exception that is raised from the click.

Comment: Edited to include the while loop, to loop until there is no error