# Unit Testing Assert Equal: Alternate Expected Result

Tags: python, unit-testing

Is there a way to use assertEqual, but with an alternate expected result?
That is, if the test failed for one expected result it will test again with the alternate result.

Comment: Please elaborate more. I assume you need to use try/exception handling instead of the assert. please check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606919/in-python-try-until-no-error) and if it didn't help, please elaborate more on your issue.

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```
self.assertTrue(result == expected or result == alternate)
```

Comment: Or `self.assertIn(result, [expected, alternate, ...])`